# Angular - href link doesn't work in IOS app

Tags: ios, angular, iphone, mobile, hyperlink

I have a web application in Angular, which is also converted (correct me if I call it the wrong way) to IOS app and I can open it in testflight app. My links which redirect to outer pages in new tabs are not working. Emails too. I have been trying to open app in a simulator but the console doesn't show any problems. My buttons simply don't work, but only on this app. When I open app on my iPhone in safari it works fine. Have you any idea what's going wrong?

As I mentioned, I tried using the simulator to find a possible error in the console. However, nothing of the sort occurs.

An example of my button implementation:

```
<a [href]="item?.link"target="_blank"class="no-text-decoration">
   <app-custom button[color]="CustomButtonColor.Dark" 
               [id]="'{{item?.name}}Button'" 
               [type]="CustomButtonType.ButtonExpanded">
        {{ 'profile.legalItems.read'| translate }} 
   </app-custom-button> 
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

One solution to this issue would be to remove the target="_blank" attribute and use the window.open() function to open the links in a new tab. Here is an example of how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
    <app-custom-button (click)="openLink(item?.link)" [color]="CustomButtonColor.Dark" [id]="'{{item?.name}}Button'" [type]="CustomButtonType.ButtonExpanded"> {{ 'profile.legalItems.read'| translate }} </app-custom-button>

openLink(url: string) {
  window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

Alternatively, you can also try using the window.open() function with the target parameter set to '_blank'.

```
<a [href]="item?.link" (click)="openLink(item?.link)" class="no-text-decoration"> <app-custom-button [color]="CustomButtonColor.Dark" [id]="'{{item?.name}}Button'" [type]="CustomButtonType.ButtonExpanded"> {{ 'profile.legalItems.read'| translate }} </app-custom-button> </a>
openLink(url: string) {
  window.open(url, '_blank');
  return false;
}
```